# How to pass parameter name from jsp page to a method of bean and then call that method in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, parameter-passing

I have the following code in a `.jsp` page

```
<td style="${r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
    <fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.## (" var="nn">    </fmt:formatNumber>
    <c:out value="${nn}"></c:out>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback ne 0}">
            <fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback)/r.p44_readback}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" type="percent" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
            <c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out><c:out value=")"></c:out></c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:out value="00%)"></c:out>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</td>
```

Now I want to pass the parameter **p44_readback** as an argument into a method eg getTabledb()of bean class.Then I want to call this bean method againg in jsp and **compare the value returned by method with r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback**.

How to pass this specific parameter into bean method and in Bean I will use this argument to retrieve value from database.This retrieved value from database then will be compared in JSP Page.

Is this the way to do it,I think I'm wrong .

```
String no= (String) pageContext.getAttribute("p44_readback");
ref.getDbTable(no);
```

EDIT-1
I tried as

```
<%
String n= "p49_readback";
ref.getDbTable(n);


%>
<c:set value="${ref.getDbTable(param.n)}" var="db"></c:set>    

<td style="${r.p49_dacbyadc-row.p49_dacbyadc le db ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
```

I simply need to pass String n value into method and then retrieve data corresponding to String n from database and then through this code

```
 <c:set value="${ref.getDbTable(param.n)}" var="db"></c:set>
```

I needed to retrieve value of getDbtable(argument) and compare this in td tag.
 I think I'm not able to retrieve value of getDbTable method.

Comment: yup,but I didn't worked

Comment: To pass a parameter to the JSP you can use `param`.

Comment: @RomanC,please see my edit,I tried param,but I think I tried it in wrong way.

Comment: @RomanC, I can't understand what to write in parenthesis of method ref.getDbTable( ) to retrieve its value from java bean .